# How to concatenate post_title with post_content with html - wordpress

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, facebook

I'm using `get_post(post_id)` to get `post_title` and `post_content`. I would like to concatenate them, that `post_title` will become first paragraph in new string.

Eg.

```
$post_title = 'Hi all, welcome here'
$post_content = 'lorem ipsum bla bla la
new paragraph bla bla bla
new paragrapg lorem ipsum'
```

And I expect result like this:

> Hi all, welcome here
>   lorem ipsum bla bla la
>   new paragraph bla bla bla
>   new paragrapg lorem ipsum

But I don't know how to pass new paragraph character after `post_title`. In db  view (mysql) there are no tags only spaces or hidden charecters. I was trying:

```
$new_string = $post_title.'/r/n'.$post_content
$new_string = '<p>'.$post_title.'</p>'.$post_content
```

But it won't work.

After this operation I would like to use `apply_filters('the_content', $new_content)` to get right view of this new string and send it to facebook fanpage using facebook SDK.

Comment: `\r\n`, then `nl2br()`; or `<br />`

Comment: Someone needs to read up on some PHP basics: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: Thanks for answers and a trace. This one works for me:


`$new_string = $post_title.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.$post_content;`

Comment: Cannot edit previous answer
@CBroe - Exactly double quote was right answer. It's normal behaviour  that `<br> = "\n"` and `<p> = "\n\n"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use nl2br() function to have line breaks in your paragraph. It will convert all \n to new lines.

```
$new_string = nl2br($post_title.$post_content);
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for me. Right answer is to use **double quote**  in `"\n\n"` or use PHP_EOL twice.